# How many positive pairof integral values (x,y) exist which satisfy $2xy-4x^2+12x-5y=11?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many positive pairof integral values (x,y) exist which satisfy $2xy-4x^2+12x-5y=11?$

My attempt: $y=(4x^2-12x+11)/(2x-5)=\dfrac{(4x^2-10x)-(2x-5)+6}{2x-5}=2x-1+6/(2x-5)$

For any such pair 6/(2x-5) should be integer  which is  not true. So there is no such pair.

But the answer say there are 2. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It is an integer if $x=3$, also if $x=2$. Also $x=4$. Also $\dots$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

As $2x-5$ is odd for integer $x$

and the odd factors of $6$ are $\pm1,\pm3$

we need $2x-5$ to be one of the four values